# return type for strchr() non const?

Tags: c, pointers, constants, glibc

On Debian 9, with GCC 8.2, `libc6-dev:amd64` 2.27:

The man page for `strchr` (and many other `<string.h>` functions) has this prototype:

```
   char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

How can it return a non-`const` `char *`, when its source is a `const char *`?

Shouldn't the prototype be `const char *strchr(const char *str, int c);` ?

Comment: C++ has issues with `strchr()` precisely because of this.  It has two overloads, one for `const char *` argument with `const char *` return type, and one with `char *` argument and `char *` return type.  It's one of the many differences between C and C++.

Comment: Don't forget that `strchr()` predates standard C.  It doesn't modify its input string, so `const char *` is appropriate for the argument.  But there wasn't `const` before the standard, so `char *` was the original return type.  With standard C, this becomes a bit uncomfortable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Shouldn't the prototype be `const char *strchr(const char *str, int c);`

No due to backward compatibility and wider applicability.

In C's early days `const` did not exist and `strchr()` was effectivley like

```
char *strchr(char *str, int c);
```

With the addition of `const`, changing the `str` argument from `char *` to `const char *` did not break existing code yet nicely allowed new code to pass `char *` or `const char *` to `strchr()`.  That `const` in the signature also indicated that `strchr(const char *str, ...)` did not alter the data pointed to by `str`.

Returning `const char *` from  `strchr()` would have broken existing code.  Further when `strchr()` is called with a `char *`, returning a `char *` is fine.  With function overloading, as in C++, both  functions exists.

```
char *strchr(char *str, int c);
const char *strchr(const char *str, int c);
```

---

The same issue applies to many other functions: `strto...(), bsearch(), memchr(), strpbrk(), strrchr(), strstr(), ...`

---

It is a consideration for new code, should you developed a function that returns a pointer derived from a supplied pointer: return `const` or not, or form 2 functions (perhaps steered by `_Generic`)?

```
const_or_not char *foo(const char *s)
```

Comment: Why two answers in lieu of one?

Comment: @machine_1 SO interface sometimes replicates things.  One answer deleted.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought something weird was going on :)

Comment: In new code you can use `_Generic` to have the return type match the argument

Comment: Your const_or_not question is a good one. I had to answer it yesterday, because this whole thing started with me developing a `strnchr()` and a `strnchrnul()`, which I needed to implement a `strlfgrep()` (a `fgrep`-like function to work on `char *`). I concluded that as you (the caller) already have the non-const pointer, you don't need the returned pointer to be non-const. In fact it's typical usage (at least me) is to do pointer subtraction and get the position of the finding, so with a `const` you are OK. In fact, returning non-const would be dangerous if you used a string literal as input.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Also consider 2 alternatives: use `_Generic()` to steer `foo()`code to 2 different functions `foo_const()`, `foo_nonconst()`. 2) redefine the interface.  I find returning the pointer not so informative as other options.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `const` is just indicating that `strchr` won't be changing the string on you. It is up to the caller to determine if the string can be modified or not.

e.g.

```
void myFn(const char* param)
{
    char* p = strchr(param, 'A');
    /* I know there should be a NULL check too ;-) */
    *p = 'Z';
}
```

would be illegal but if the param was not `const` it would be fine.